# Can static variables exist in Dafny?

Tags: dafny

In a verification context, we usually pass values to functions in order to isolate them as "units" from the surrounding context. However, from a programming point-of-view, static fields have their uses too.

Since Dafny compiles to the .NET Platform, it's reasonable to expect some way of exposing static variables.

For example, for implementing the Singleton pattern I would expect something like:

```
class A { constructor () {}
  static var instance: A? := null;
  static method getInstance() returns (r: A)
    ensures A.instance() != null
  {
    if A.instance == null { var i := new A(); A.instance := i; }
    r := A.instance;
  }
}
```

However, that results in the error `Fields cannot be declared 'static'.`

Is there any way of expressing this (without using uninterpreted functions, because that might work just for verification purposes but would not generate useful code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in Dafny today for objects. You'll need to pass the singleton object around as a parameter.

If you don't need an object and instead can get by with an immutable value, then you can use a `const` (either a `static const` inside a class or trait, or a module-level `const`).

This issue has come up from time to time, especially in the context of standard input and output. I have a sketch of a `resource` design for such singleton objects (a little like `object` in Scala or akin to `once` in Eiffel), but it has never reached top priority. You are welcome to try to convince me otherwise (or to propose and provide such a feature yourself).

Rustan